# Office ODT removes SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365, office

Does anyone know how to install Office 2019, with the Office Deployment Tool (ODT), on a computer with SharePoint 2019?  ODT keeps uninstalling SharePoint.

In the ODT config file there is an optional tab `<RemoveMSI>`.

1. If I do not include the tag

   ODT install refuses to Office because SharePoint is installed
2. If I have it

   ODT installs Office but removes SharePoint, no warning at all!
3. There is a sub-tag `<Ignore Product>`, however, I have to have Product Id to use it.  Product Id seems to be string that is defined by ODT, instead of something that can be found on the Programs themselves; ODT comes with files that appear to define the Product Ids.

   I have successfully prevented other Office programs from being uninstalled; for example, SharePoint Designer.  However, I have not come across a Product Id specifically for SharePoint or an Id for a suite that includes SharePont.

Config File

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
      <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume">
         <Language ID="en-us" />
      </Product>
  </Add>
  <RemoveMSI>
    <IgnoreProduct ID="SharePointDesigner" />
  </RemoveMSI>
</Configuration>
```

Background:

- This is for a Development box.  My company is moving away from MSI
  version of Office and I will have to use the ODT version soon.

Comment: Any reason you're installing office on a SharePoint server?

Comment: @CallumCrowley, It is a Development box and I was able to do it in the past with MSI version of Office.  I find that Excel helps with Development.

Comment: can you not just connect to your development SharePoint server from another machine that has Excel installed? This is actually a more realistic test environment, since Office would never be installed on a SharePoint server farm.

Comment: @CallumCrowley, also, now that I know this is a problem, I don't like that ODT just uninstalls SharePoint without warning; it's an unexpected result.  I have to rebuild my Dev Farm because of this.  If there is a simple way to block the uninstall, I think, I should; no one should be installing ODT on a Production SharePoint Server but a lot of things aren't supposed to happen, happen.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do not support installing Microsoft Office and SharePoint on the same computer:

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019#minimum-requirements-for-sharepoint-servers-in-a-farm)

I would recommend using Office from another machine which can access your development server.